# ios: creating own view

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiview, view

I'm only starting to developing iOS apps. So the question is gonna be nooby i guess..

I'm trying to understand how the mvc model works in iOS developing.

I want to mix available views and my own (which I want to draw by myself using primitives such as drawing strings)

So

I created the MyView:UIView class. Then I overrided drawRect method and added there a simple output. Then I added my class to the "ipad display" using interface builder.

And the problem is that breakpoint in the beginning of the DrawRect method never gets reached. And of course I get a blank screen in simulator=(

I've tried to add ViewController and use it in the interface builder but in fact i don't need it because my view just draws a constant string and that's all...

I guess I misunderstand something very serious because looking through apple examples got nothing for me.

Here's my code (sorry, forgot about it):

MyView.h:

```
@interface MyView : UIView {
...
}
```

MyView.m:

```
...
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    NSString *text = @"Hello, world";

    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];

    [[UIColor blackColor] set];
    CGPoint point;
    point = CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.5f);
    [text drawAtPoint:point withFont:font];

    [font release];
}
```

UPD:

I've added a TabBar just to make sure that the problem is only with my own view. That's it: TabBar appears.

Comment: It would be easier to spot your mistake if you posted your code.

Comment: Do you have a view object associated with your window in MainWindow.xib? If so, make sure that the class of this view object is MyView. What I'm trying to get at is that your application is creating a view from a nib file when it starts up and you want to make sure that the view being created is of the type MyView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you didn't post your code, this is a wild guess, but you need to make the view re-render:

```
[myViewInstance setNeedsDisplay:YES];
```

Also, make sure the view is actually loaded. You can check this with a little NSLog in the nib awaking method (`-[<NSNibAwaking> awakeFromNib]`).

Comment: where should I do that (re-render my view) ?

Comment: In fact I can't even understand who creates the view. Maybe it's hidden in the nib but it's just a guess...

Comment: by "creating the view" I meant allocating memory and initialization.

Comment: If `drawRect:` is never being called, then the issue isn't `setNeedsDisplay:`. `-drawRect:` will be called at least once when you're put on screen the first time.

Answer (score 0):

If `drawRect:` is not being called, then either you are not actually onscreen, or you have put in the wrong signature for `drawRect:`. The correct signature is:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
```

To make sure you're actually onscreen, try overloading `awakeFromNib` and putting a breakpoint there. If you're not, then you have not configured it correctly in interface builder. The most common problems are failure to set the correct class for the view (it should be set to MyView), or putting it into a NIB that is not actually loaded.

And of course make sure that you are actually a subclass of `UIView`, that you do not have any warnings from the compiler or from Interface Builder, and that there are no messages printed to console when you run.

Comment: It looks like my signature is correct (being honest - I've just uncommented the stub=))

By the way how can I override a method without worrying about making a typo?

To do that I go to the base class implementation (by option-double_click) and copy from there. It looks like there's a better way, isn't it?

That's my first xcode (and mac) experience - sorry...

Comment: The best way in Xcode 3 is to copy from the header files. Xcode 4 does a better job of auto-completing the signatures for you.